# What is the proper syntax for LIKE?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to perform the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name_here WHERE Date LIKE %Jan % 2014%
```

Now, the table name is different and hidden here, but it just won't go through. It says there is an error in my syntax around  `%Jan % 2014%`

I can get this to work, so I know the connection works: `SELECT * FROM table_name_here`
So the problem lies with the `WHERE` and `LIKE` part.

I also tried to perform this on my hosting sites DB management tool:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table_name` 
WHERE  `Date` LIKE  '%Jan % 2014%'
```

and that one works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two syntax errors, firstly the word `Date` is a keyword, so needs to be wrapped and you need quotes around your string, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name_here WHERE `Date` LIKE "%Jan % 2014%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `date` is begin stored as a date/datetime column, don't use `like` on it.  The `like` implicitly converts it to a string, using some local format.

Instead, be explicit:

```
where month(`date`) = 1 and year(`date`) = 2014
```

or

```
where date_format(`date`, '%Y-%m') = '2014-01'
```

As for your original question, you discovered that quotes are important around string constants.  I would recommend using single quotes (as opposed to double quotes), because single quotes are the ANSI standard string delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around your `LIKE` match:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name_here WHERE Date LIKE "%Jan % 2014%"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DATE datatype, you can use this

`SELECT * FROM table_name_here WHERE 'Date' LIKE '2014-01-%'`

this is how mysql store the DATE value: 'YYYY-MM-DD' eg. '2014-01-07.

[MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)